# Can I put a junction box between the panel and a GFI?

Tags: electrical, junction-box, circuit, gfi

I want to put a junction box between the panel and a GFI on a 15 Amp designated circuit. Any issues with this?

Comment: Is it designated or dedicated?  Dedicated you can't add another circuit from the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the limited information you have provided, the answer is 'yes'. You can put junction boxes basically anywhere in any type of circuit. You will still need to make the connections properly within the junction box.

Comment: And maintain accessiblity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's perfectly fine for GFCI, because a GFCI is about protecting people, not protecting wires. The GFCI (breaker, dead front or receptacle) has to be at or before the first load that requires protection.

On the other hand, an Arc Fault Circuit Interrupter (AFCI) protects wires. AFCI usually needs to be at the breaker, but can be farther along at a junction box provided the wiring is in metal conduit. I am pretty sure PVC and other non-metal conduit do not have that exception, and definitely nm cable (Romex) does not.